# Angular Cli support for inline templates and css

Tags: angular-cli

Does latest version of Angular cli supports inline templates and css for components ? i dont see --inline-template option there anymore ?

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your angular-cli.json file you can specify if you want your files to have inline css and templates.

Here you can find all the options that you can specify in the config file.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-cli

That way, when you use `ng generate component` it will use the defaults.

```
{
    "project": {
      "version": "1.0.0-beta.22-1",
      "name": "client"
    },
    "apps": [
      {
        "root": "src",
        "outDir": "build",
        "assets": [
          "assets",
          "favicon.ico"
        ],
        "index": "index.html",
        "main": "main.ts",
        "test": "test.ts",
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
        "prefix": "ws",
        "mobile": false,
        "styles": [
          "styles/main.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": [],
        "environments": {
          "source": "environments/environment.ts",
          "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
          "dev": "environments/environment.dev.ts"
        }
      }
    ],
    "addons": [],
    "packages": [],
    "e2e": {
      "protractor": {
        "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "karma": {
        "config": "./karma.conf.js"
      }
    },
    "defaults": {
      "styleExt": "scss",
      "prefixInterfaces": false,
      "inline": {
        "style": true, <<<--- CHECK IT OUT!!
        "template": true
      },
      "spec": {
        "class": false,
        "component": true,
        "directive": true,
        "module": false,
        "pipe": true,
        "service": true
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

In the current version of the CLI (version 6) I just created a new project with `ng new foo -s -t`. The `-s` and `-t` set the defaults for inline templates and inline styles to true. Then I opened the `angular.json` and looked at what it did.

Inside of the `"project"` property of each app... there is a `"schematics"` property. Inside of that, it added the following:

```
"@schematics/angular:component": {
    "inlineTemplate": true,
    "inlineStyle": true
}
```

If you add this, and then attempt to generate a component, the template and the styles will default to inline.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Angular CLI: 10.1.3

you can use the cli `"ng g c component-name -is -it"` to create a component with inline styles and inline template.

1. g - generate
2. c  - component
3. is - inline-style
4. it - inline-template

you can also use `"ng generate component component-name -is -it"`

Answer (score 0):

Support for camel case arguments has been deprecated and will be removed in a future major version.
Use '--inline-style' instead of '--inlineStyle'.

When I update them to 14 via ng update, then --inlineStyle eg no longer work

```
ng g c component-name--inline-template=true --inline-style=true
```

Comment: This appears to be commentary on one of the other answers, but not an original answer. For what it's worth, no one on this thread—not the OP, nor any of the answers—suggest using `--inlineStyle` as a command line argument. (Though one answer suggests using `inlineStyle` as part of the `schematics` property.)